# How to find out if a subgrid is being displayed

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way to tell if a subgrid is currently being displayed? I need this information to resize the parent grid(s).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to check if the subgrid row exists and is visible.
jqGrid creates a row under the parent row which is combination of the id of the jqGrid +  _rowId + _expandedContent.

Knowing the id of the row and the id of jqGrid you can easy check

```
var res = $("#jqGrid").find("#jqGrid_"+rowId+"_expandedContent");
if(res.length && !res.is(":hidden") ) {
    alert("subgrid is displayed");
} else  {
    alert("subgrid is not displayed");
}
```

where jqGrid is the id of jqGrid and rowId is the id of the row.